# Counting complete rows of a data frame in R - data programming course

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to write a code which (1) reads a specified range of files from a directory, (2) counts the number of complete rows in each file and (3) returns my answer as a 2 column data frame (with specified column names).

```
complete <- function(directory, ID){
   filelist <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)[ID]
      x <- lapply(filelist, function(x){read.csv(x, header = TRUE)})
          y <- complete.cases(data.frame(x))
              z <- sum(y*1)
                 print(z)
  }
```

It works for 1 file but not a range, if I used complete("directory", 1:2) I get:

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1461, 3652

Once I can obtain the number of complete values I think i can work out how to return a data frame.

Thanks in advance,

Rose

Comment: You can multiply the logical vectors by 1 ... this will leave you with 1 for every `TRUE` and a 0 for every `FALSE` ... this is then easily summed up and gives you the total count.

Comment: @Val I tried that and while it worked for 1 file, when I used a range (e.g. 1:2) I got the following error

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1461, 3652

Comment: Hard to say without any info about your files ... but the error means you're assigning a variable to the `data.frame` which has either more or less observations than the df has rows.

Comment: @Val I haven't set a row number for the dataframe - using data.frame() was just my attempted work-around due to the error:
"Error in complete.cases(x) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument"

Comment: a `data.frame` has traditionally a number of observations (rows) per variable (column). Nothing you have to set there. But if you try to add to that `data.frame` you need a variable which fits to the `data.frame`'s dimensions

Comment: @Val, I understand what you're saying however I need a code which will cope with 1:332 (or anywhere in between) files...is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can read one of your files and use `dput()` to share it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

This may work to get what you're after

```
complete <- function(directory){
  # Get list of csv files in directory
  filelist <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)

  # Get a list of dataframes for all csv files in the directory
  list.df <- lapply(filelist, function(x){read.csv(x, header = TRUE)})

  # Get a list of complete rows for each dataframe in the list
  complete.casesums <- lapply(list.df, function(x) sum(complete.cases(x)))

  # Get a list of incomplete rows for each dataframe in the list
  incomplete.casesums <- lapply(list.df, function(x) sum(!complete.cases(x)))

  # Create a dataframe with the filename, number of complete rows, and number of incomplete rows
  df <- data.frame(cbind(filelist, complete.casesums, incomplete.casesums), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # Return the dataframe
  return(df)
}

# Call the function
(df <- complete("C:/Path/To/Folder"))
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks - I'll try that method. I need to make the files called modifiable with a second argument but that shouldn't be too difficult....